# Code Completion in Delphi XE 2 doesn't work with .pas files from Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

I just can't use the code completion in Delphi XE 2 when I open or even copy pascal code from Delphi 7. Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: No problems here. You need the code to actually be able to compile. Does it? If you want help then you'll probably need to show us how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't know whether this applies to Delphi XE2 as well, but after upgrading to Delphi XE we had to delete the .dproj files and let Delphi re-create them from the .dpr files to get code Completion to work.

Comment: Also, delete all *.dcu, *.local and *.identcache files.

Comment: You also could try to install the IDE Fix Pack from Andreas Hausladen http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack-2009-10/

Comment: Hi everyone. Well, some days ago I've tried to make a simple Project with the Delphi 7 very simple and just with native componentes (Just a single form with some TEdits). After create and save my project, I opened the **.dpr** file in my Delphi XE 2 IDE and tried to use the Code completion function but didn't work. So, after I installed the IDE Fix Pack thath @Lars told me to download it seems to work correctly. Anyway, thnx a lot everyone! =D

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for your problem is installing the IDE Fix Pack.

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack-2009-10/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to delete your .dproj and lose your settings, you can first check that the following "DCC_UnitAlias" line is not missing :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
    <DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName>aida.exe</DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName>
    <DCC_UnitAlias>WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;$(DCC_UnitAlias)</DCC_UnitAlias>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you don't see it, make a backup copy of the dproj and just add the missing line at the proper place (`<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">`)